# Where are the zeros of a slightly perturbed Riemann Zeta function?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

We seek to understand the locations of the zeros when we introduce a minor perturbation to the Riemann Zeta function:

${\displaystyle \zeta (s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{n^{s}}}={\frac {1}{1^{s}}}+{\frac {1}{2^{s}}}+{\frac {1}{3^{s}}}+{\frac {1}{4^{s}}}+\cdots}$

For instance, consider the following slightly perturbed Zeta function:

${\displaystyle N(s)={\frac {1}{1^{s}}}+{\frac {2}{2^{s}}}+{\frac {1}{3^{s}}}+{\frac {1}{4^{s}}}+\cdots}$

Where are its zeros located on the complex plane? (We can assume the Riemann Hypothesis is true.)

Comment: Your function appears to be $\zeta(s) + \frac{1}{2^s}$.  What does this tell you about the zeros?

Comment: I do NOT know. That is why I asked the question. It is a "slightly perturbed" zeta.

Comment: Taking a guess at the kind of answer you're looking for, would someone just plugging your function into a CAS like Wolfram Engine and spitting out a handful of approximate zeros suffice?

Comment: Very interesting question. Did someone perhaps write a code for a small pertubation of the form $\frac{\epsilon}{2^s}$ in which we can see the zeroes shift away from the "Riemann" positions for varying $\epsilon$ around $0$?

Comment: `(*start*) (*Mathematica 8*)
n = 20;
epsilon = 1/10^10;
s = 1 + 14*I; N[
 s + 1/n + 
  1/(1 - Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*
        Binomial[n - 1, 
          k - 1]/(HarmonicNumber[10^10000, s + k/n] + 
           epsilon/2^(s + k/n)), {k, 1, n}]/
      Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*
        Binomial[n - 1, 
          k - 1]/(HarmonicNumber[10^10000, s + k/n + 1/n] + 
           epsilon/2^(s + k/n + 1/n)), {k, 1, n}]), 15] (*end*)`

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze

Comment: @
Mats Granvik Thank you so much. The code works. I don't understand it but, as you said,  it gives the results expexted from the calculation of davidlowryduda.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thanks! I have sort of a proof of it here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/439430/25104 It is basically a ratio of consecutive higher order derivatives of any function, here the Generalized harmonic numbers in the complex plane when the real part of $s$ is equal to, or greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a graph showing the first 10 zeroes of the modified $\zeta$-function
$$f(s) = \zeta(s) + \epsilon / 2^{s}\tag{1}$$
in the complex $s$-plane together with the original Riemann zeroes. The picture neatly shows how a specific zero (black) is shifted due to a positive (blue) and negative (red) perturbation.

[image]

A modified zero has been calculated with the Mathematica code shown below using 30 iterations of the Newton algorithm with the initial value equal to the corresponding Riemann zero. The imaginary parts of the Riemann zeroes were taken from https://www.lmfdb.org/zeros/zeta/, the real part is taken as $0.5$ following the Riemann hypothesis.

For those who have access to Mathematica here is the code:

```
(* The function zeroes230902 calculates the zeroes n1 through n2 *)
(* of a modified zeta function f(s,eps)=Zeta(s)+eps delta(s)     *)
(* using Newton iteration with iter steps                        *)
(* and initial values equal to the corresponding Riemann zero.   *)
(* The imaginary parts of the Riemannian zeroes,stored externally*)
(* in zr0,are taken from https://www.lmfdb.org/zeros/zeta/       *)
(**)
(* Example of the function call:                                 *)
(* zeroes230902[0.3,5,2,6,Function[s,1/2^s]]                     *)

zeroes230902[eps_, iter_, n1_, n2_, delta_] :=
 Module[{x, t, z, del, f, f1, zr},
  del[s_] = delta[s]; f[s_, epsilon_] = Zeta[s] + epsilon* del[s]; 
  f1[s_, epsilon_] = D[f[s, epsilon], s];
  zr = Take[zr0, {1, 50}];  (* sample of the first 50 Riemann zeroes *)
  x = Table[z[1] = N[1 + zr[[j]] I];
    t = Table[
      z[k + 1] = N[z[k] - f[z[k], eps]/f1[z[k], eps]], {k, 1, iter}];
    t[[-1]], {j, n1, n2}];
  x]
```

Example call

```
zeroes230902[0.0, 15, 3, 5, Function[s, 1/2^s]]
zeroes230902[+0.3, 15, 3, 5, Function[s, 1/2^s]]
zeroes230902[-0.3, 15, 3, 5, Function[s, 1/2^s]]

{0.5 + 25.0109 I, 0.5 + 30.4249 I, 0.5 + 32.9351 I}
{0.438434 + 24.8655 I, 0.520432 + 30.5937 I,  0.523301 + 32.7755 I}
{0.557216 + 25.1517 I, 0.4778 + 30.2692 I, 0.474581 + 33.0804 I}
```

**Discussion**

§1. Approximate shifted root position

Writing the approximate root $s$ of $f(s)=\zeta(s) + \epsilon \delta(s)$ as $s(s_0) =s_0 + \epsilon \eta(s0)$ where $s_0$ is the Riemann zero in question we obtain to first order in $\epsilon$

$$\eta(s_0) = - \frac{\delta(s_0)}{\zeta'(s_0)}\tag{2}$$

This is actually the first iteration of the Newton algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

Broadly speaking, taking linear combinations of $L$-functions give functions that have many zeros near the half-line, but also with many zeros all over. There isn't a *good* way to find these zeros, but it's not very hard to simply go and compute some.

For the function $f(s) = \zeta(s) + \frac{1}{2^s}$, I computed a couple hundred zeros nearish the critical line. It would be possible to do this rigorously using Cauchy's residue formula, but I just used Newton's method on a mesh of points and removed duplicates.

The first (that I found --- this list is probably not complete) several zeros are at the bottom of this post.

As one can see, they appear somewhat random. There are some in the region of absolute convergence, for example $s_1 =  1.18155595111619 + 13.8549476070918i$. These are perhaps easier to verify, as elementary estimates show $\zeta(s_1) \approx 0.433 - 0.078i$ and $2^{-s_1} \approx -0.433 + 0.078i$.

```
 0.608530371934972 + 4.26404281725873*I,
 1.18155595111619 + 13.8549476070918*I, 
 0.261075254600588 + 24.5028774589355*I,
 0.686982196357885 + 21.6442678405853*I,
 0.571594889811657 + 32.2809480702920*I,
 0.561799649178136 + 31.1069189276823*I,
 1.01312826981529 + 40.9493043996571*I, 
 0.203247036583049 + 37.7669305594545*I,
 0.186720476429387 + 43.1268593041915*I,
 1.06217193214242 + 49.6288652866812*I, 
 0.154647361762731 + 48.2984359646153*I,
 0.280290010982236 + 52.8103229795903*I,
 0.328892676559822 + 56.6784515719099*I,
 1.07330622162077 + 59.3143586659668*I, 
 0.148567213296437 + 60.6583689501593*I,
 0.852060595678997 + 67.3648328248167*I,
 0.233749117077807 + 65.1791033894777*I,
 0.519567441565179 + 69.1985153917912*I,
 1.08936593388872 + 76.9852236089313*I, 
 0.289524729109100 + 72.0811381328665*I,
 0.221582207466821 + 76.0008445141189*I,
 0.300987803269673 + 79.1846342707407*I,
 0.674568639974302 + 85.0448504258809*I,
 0.785608699658067 + 87.1120055376591*I,
 0.268475682232423 + 82.9370204326388*I,
 0.231264557697083 + 88.7894192739031*I,      
 0.304547844294147 + 92.5719742617833*I,
 0.249756762588726 + 95.4100949549107*I, 
 1.08817834429472 + 95.0930248700267*I, 
 0.347904167782075 + 101.453461013395*I,
 0.343288657447096 + 98.7434579783956*I,
 0.607243131219802 + 104.995833748037*I,
 0.760594236525269 + 104.086748243230*I,
 0.297351145257549 + 107.157040613773*I,
 0.324203981537656 + 116.128146491521*I,
 0.678548857618410 + 114.053889595655*I,
 0.828118815715211 + 112.262665310805*I,
 0.193164111887456 + 110.980403788449*I,
 1.01999324921567 + 122.659106050461*I,
 0.255140693697753 + 124.164092823984*I,
 0.354403227545831 + 118.862047509191*I,
 0.406102087685723 + 121.711037835340*I,
 0.891034645359411 + 131.099003129259*I,
 0.345620089609479 + 127.493221027943*I,
 0.527445710540387 + 133.201657260850*I,
 0.350576787494291 + 129.832341026987*I,
 0.304781739406574 + 134.808085827953*I,
 0.827065612049055 + 140.337788997085*I,
 0.569158444824640 + 140.543492560166*I,
 0.354820706721776 + 143.022900523662*I,
 0.314393290186259 + 138.175819876305*I,
 0.320523916303474 + 145.976972479331*I,
 1.06983130596373 + 150.083689086408*I,
 0.507889147920485 + 147.664900282908*I,
 0.191154908041025 + 150.682864581192*I,
```

---

**Edit to include code**

The following is a basic implementation for this problem in the free CAS sagemath.

```
def f(s):
    return CC(zeta(s)) + CC(2**(-s))

def fprime(s):
    return CC(zetaderiv(1, s)) - CC(2**(CC(-s)) * CC(log(2)))

def newton(s0, iters=50, toofar=10, verbose=False):
    scurrent = s0
    snext = 0
    for _ in range(iters):
        if abs(scurrent - s0) > toofar:
            return None
        snext = scurrent - f(scurrent) / fprime(scurrent)
        if verbose:
            print(snext)
        scurrent = snext
    return scurrent

def isolate(cands, tolerance=1e-3):
    ret = []
    for cand in cands:
        if any(abs(cand - r) < tolerance for r in ret):
            continue
        ret.append(cand)
    return ret

def collect_zeros():
    cands = [newton(CC(0.5 + 1j * k)) for k in range(200)]
    cands = [cand for cand in cands if cand is not None]
    zeros = isolate(cands)
    zeros.sort(key = lambda z : z.imag())
    return zeros
```

I briefly describe this code. Newton's method takes the form of iterations

$$ z_{n+1} = z_n - \frac{f(z_n)}{f'(z_n)}. $$

The iterates $z_n$ will tend to a zero if the initial guess is close enough.  The poorly named `f(s)` function is calculates $\zeta(s) + 2^{-s}$. (Actually, it asks PARI/GP to compute $\zeta(s)$ and adds $2^{-s}$ to it). I also hardcode in the derivative, using sage's `zetaderiv` (which actually calls mpmath's $\zeta'(s)$ evaluator) and a hardcoded derivative of $2^{-s}$.

An oddity here is that I put many things in `CC()`. In sage, this tells the computation to occur in double precision. Sage would rather try to keep things algebraically pure, which has a significant computational burden and is unnecessary here.

The function `newton(s0, iters, toofar, verbose)` is a function that performs `iters` many Newton iterations beginning with `s0`. In principle, iterations might find some far away zero. But I didn't want to deal with that, so if any iterate goes more than `toofar` away from `s0`, then I terminate the iteration and return `None`. (This is not great coding style). And because it is sometimes nice to see how things go, I also threw in a `verbose` flag, which just prints out iterates as they are computed.

Then I include two convenience functions. The function `isolate(cands, tolerance)` takes a list of potential zeros and reduces them so that no two zeros are within `tolerance` of each other. When using Newton's method on a mesh, you'll find the same zero repeatedly. I assumed that no two zeros will be within $0.001$ of each other --- at least, in the range I'm computing with. Direct inspection suggests this is true, but I note that it's not *obviously* true.

And the final convenience function is `collect_zeros()`, which runs Newton's method on a 1D mesh on the half-line up to $1/2 + 200i$. It removes duplicates (as described above) and sorts based on imaginary part. It is naive. On my machine, this ran in approximately 20 seconds.

With this short script, one can do

```
> zs = collect_zeros()   # took ~20s on my machine
> all(abs(f(z)) < 1e-12 for z in zs)
True
> zs[:20]
[0.261967395716187,
 0.608530371934972 + 4.26404281725873*I,
 1.18155595111619 + 13.8549476070918*I,
 0.686982196357885 + 21.6442678405853*I,
 0.261075254600588 + 24.5028774589355*I,
 0.561799649178136 + 31.1069189276823*I,
 0.571594889811657 + 32.2809480702920*I,
 0.203247036583049 + 37.7669305594545*I,
 1.01312826981529 + 40.9493043996571*I,
 0.186720476429387 + 43.1268593041915*I,
 0.154647361762731 + 48.2984359646153*I,
 1.06217193214242 + 49.6288652866812*I,
 0.280290010982236 + 52.8103229795903*I,
 0.328892676559822 + 56.6784515719099*I,
 1.07330622162077 + 59.3143586659668*I,
 0.148567213296437 + 60.6583689501593*I,
 0.233749117077807 + 65.1791033894777*I,
 0.852060595678997 + 67.3648328248167*I,
 0.519567441565179 + 69.1985153917912*I,
 0.289524729109100 + 72.0811381328665*I]
```

It should not be hard to improve this code, or to modify it for similar situations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible for you to share your code for the Newton's method you implemented ? so I can try with other slightly perturbed Zeta function ?

Comment: @david https://mathoverflow.net/q/375886/25104

Comment: @david Sure. But I'll note that I didn't save the code I wrote yesterday, and I don't remember what mesh I ran it on. But the idea is straightforward, so I'll include it in an edit.

Answer (score 3):

It might be of interest to mention the Bombieri-Hejhal result on the (off-the-line) zeros of linear combinations of two $L$-functions that individually have the same functional equation... namely, the Hecke L-functions attached to the trivial and non-trivial class-group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$:  On the
distribution of zeros of linear combinations of Euler products}, Duke
Math. J. 80 (1995), 821-862.

In that case (unsurprisingly), there are many off-line zeros... but/and something non-trivial can be said about their distributions.

Answer (score 3):

(* Mathematica *)

```
n = 20; (* set n = 30 for better precision *)
s = 1 + 14*I; (* change the number s=1+14*I to get another zero closest to it *)
s + 1/n + 
  1/(1 - Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*
        Binomial[n - 1, 
          k - 1]/(HarmonicNumber[10^10000, s + k/n] + 
           1/2^(s + k/n)), {k, 1, n}]/
      Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*
        Binomial[n - 1, 
          k - 1]/(HarmonicNumber[10^10000, s + k/n + 1/n] + 
           1/2^(s + k/n + 1/n)), {k, 1, n}]);
N[%, 15]
```

Output:
`1.18155595111619 + 13.85494760709183 I`

Which matches the third zero in the list in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4756149/8530) by [davidlowryduda](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9754/davidlowryduda)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you explain the purpose of this function ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is just a more compact way of writing the ratio of consecutive higher order derivatives of the generalized Harmonic numbers, that converges to the zero (in the Voronoi cell) closest to the seed point $s$. What I find somewhat surprising is that as long as $\Re(s)\geq 1$ then the ratio converges to any zeta zero (you can factor out the trivial zeros by dividing with (x+2), (x+4), (x+6),...). Here is an explanation for how I arrived at it: https://mathoverflow.net/a/439430/25104

Comment: The mathoverflow link does not open at the intended position. The answer begins with: 

`A1 = Zeta[c]/Zeta[-0 + 0 c + s] - Zeta[c]/Zeta[-1 + 1 c + s];  
A2 = Zeta[c]/Zeta[-1 + 1 c + s] - Zeta[c]/Zeta[-2 + 2 c + s];   
A3 = Zeta[c]/Zeta[-2 + 2 c + s] - Zeta[c]/Zeta[-3 + 3 c + s];  
A4 = Zeta[c]/Zeta[-3 + 3 c + s] - Zeta[c]/Zeta[-4 + 4 c + s];  
A5 = Zeta[c]/Zeta[-4 + 4 c + s] - Zeta[c]/Zeta[-5 + 5 c + s];  
` Hope you can find it.

Comment: The starting point is the limit:

$$\text{A0}=\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$$
$$\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\text{A0} \zeta (c)-\frac{\zeta (c)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}\right) = \frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)^2}$$
Notice that:

$$-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)$$ which comes from: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T(n,k)}{n^c \cdot k^s} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow s} \zeta(z)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(z-1)}}}{n^c} = \frac{\zeta(s) \cdot \zeta(c)}{\zeta(c + s - 1)}$$